# Error: Could not resolve './src/components/uiListItem.vue' from index.js in Azure DevOps Build Pipeline

Tags: vue.js, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I am creating an Azure DevOps build pipeline for one of my `Vue.js` projects and always getting the preceding error.

[image]

> ./index.js → ./dist/bundle.esm.js... [!] Error: Could not resolve
> './src/components/uiListItem.vue' from index.js Error: Could not
> resolve './src/components/uiListItem.vue' from index.js
> at error (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/node-entry.js:5400:30)
> at ModuleLoader.handleResolveId (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/node-entry.js:12410:24)
> at ModuleLoader. (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/node-entry.js:12298:30)
> at Generator.next ()
> at fulfilled (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/node-entry.js:38:28)

The command `npm run build` and `npm run build --prod` works fine in local and the issue is only with the Pipeline environment. Here is my `azure-pipeline.yml`.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
variables:
- name: tag
  value: '$(Build.BuildId)'
- name: vmImageName
  value: 'ubuntu-latest'
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '10.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'npm install'
      inputs:
        command: 'install'
        workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
        verbose: false
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'npm run build'
      inputs:
        command: 'custom'
        workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
        customCommand: 'run build'
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the issue. In the pipeline the the `vmImage` is `ubuntu-latest` as that is a `Linux` distribution, it was unable to find the specified file, so I had to change the file references from using `./src/components/uiListItem.vue` to `src/components/uiListItem.vue` from `index.js` file. Please note that there is no `./`.

```
export { default as uiListItem } from "src/components/uiListItem.vue";
```

I just did this for all the references and the build was successful then.

[image]